# Best way to store data on page for Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page been generated that comes with an array of data generated by php. I need to use some of this data for an ajax request.

I just wondered what the best way is to store the data on the page, it's not sensitive and the page doesn't involve a form. At the moment I've been using data- attributes in a hidden div but just seems a bit messey?

eg.

```
<div id="data" class="hidden" data-question="<?= $blah ?>" data-another="<?= $blahblah ?>"></div>
```

Comment: there is no true "Best" way to do it, it all depends on your needs. Storing it in an attribute has it's benefits, but it also has pitfalls such as having to escape quotes. I personally wouldn't create an element on the page that has no purpose other than having data attributes, i'd instead store that data on a relevant element.

Comment: I think that the "best" way to store the data depends on how you intend to use them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no "best" way, I would recommend [JSON](http://json.org/) -- a format for storing and exchanging data, and would seem to fit your situation well.

Instead of storing arbitrary data in data-attributes on an html element, like this:

```
<div data-name="bob" data-age="27" data-gender="male" />
```

Json allows you to store them like this:

```
people = {
    "bob" : {"age":"27", "gender":"male"},
    "alice" {"age":"31", "gender":"female"}
}
```

You can access this data programatically through native or library calls in almost any language, especially PHP and JavaScript.

In JavaScript, JSON is accessed like this:

```
BobsAge = people['bob'].age;
```

This format allows for other programmatic access, such as looping over objects or keys, that may be difficult to perform on data-attributes of html elements.

In your case, JSON could be generated like so (although there are better ways):

```
<script>
var data = {
<? foreach ($data as $d){ ?>
    { 
        "question" : "<? $d['question'] ?>",
        "answer" : "<? $d['answer'] ?>" 
    },
<?}?>
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer! Forgive me for maybe asking another daft question though but would the JSON element created be left randomly in the page for the javascript ( that does the ajax call ) to access?

Comment: Yes, the data would be "printed out" to the html file where it could be accessed by javascript for whatever purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities:

- **attributes:** this is your approach

  This is probably best for simple strings, e.g. parameters, and data that is descriptive - e.g `data-popover` for an element which contains popover contents. Many JS plugins are built that way.
- **PHP echo in `<script>` tag**

  No "additional markup" for the cost of having `<script>` tag in the same file (and, probably, the use of global JS variables). I wouldn't recommend that.
- **additional AJAX call** fetching JSON with data from PHP

  Best for more complicated data structures, such as nested arrays or objects.